# Which is best way to learn typing on computer

Tags: typing

I want to leanr typing on computer.
Which is the besy way to learn that and rougly how much time it takes learn just normal speed so that i don't have to look at keyboard everytime i type somethng

Comment: rather off topic.. and the answer is: just type. As with every practical matter exercise is the best way to learn..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a typing software like `typing Master`